# Automatic thresholding

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I did pre-processing on images before object recognition in which following steps are included:

1. Average filter is used to remove noise
2. `bwareaopen` command is used to remove unwanted pixels.
3. Dilation and closing is also performed to get clean image.

The problem is that thresholding value of all above specified operations are set according to one image but when I change the image then all these specified thresholding values do not work for the new image.

Is there any way to set the thresholding values in such a way that they work for 30 to 40 images captured at the same time using the same camera from fixed height. As it is not possible for me to change thresholding value of operations for every image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even better, show us some images, preferably images really different, so images that would need different thresholds. Btw, a median filter is often more adapted for noise removal, because it preserves more the contrast of the image.

Comment: You can use [Otsu's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) for automatic threshold of the images. In Matlab is called using the function `graythresh`